# I would like others to explain to me how to use marriage as upward mobility strategy

Tags: society

I was thinking of fake identities and cosmetic surgery like in red rising for the upmartiagers, so this is also about tools and technologies.

Comment: What have you found on your own? It's not like that trick wasn't ever used in real life

Comment: [Hypergamy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergamy). And it is very common both in real life and in fiction, so that I don't fully grasp the reason of the question. Have you never heard of [Cinderella](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergamy)? Or read any [Jane Austen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jane_Austen), for example, [*Pride and Prejudice*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pride_and_Prejudice)? (Available [at Project Gutenberg](https://gutenberg.org/ebooks/42671).)

Comment: You're asking us to write yore story for you? .. depending on the type of upward mobility desired (wealth, status (however that's measured), power, whatever) you marry someone with more than you have of the relevant measure, everyone understands that . so where's the problem? . what issue are you asking for a solution to?

Comment: *"There institutions who to try to prevent it that is the problem especially if you do it multiple times"* hmm .. that sounds suspiciously like it's character actions you're asking us for, aka *writing your story for you*, and that is something were not here for, you may have misunderstood the sites purpose? . Have you taken [the tour](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/tour)?

Comment: The strategy of your characters? that they will use?

Comment: Then that is character choice, motive and actions isn't it.

Comment: I'm voting to close as being story-based because answers would, as a whole, be extremely dependent on the character, their personality, and their personal circumstances who wants to climb the hierarchy. Unlike military strategy, I doubt there's as much as a "winning guide" to climb up in social power :/.

Comment: You're asking for suggestions - apparently as many as seven of them. This is far too broad and open-ended for the way we work here. We deal with single clearly focused questions one per post where it's possible to converge on a "best answer", whereas here, there are potentially infinite answers. Plausibility would depend entirely on the character's and the society's circumstances and upon the action of that character. This question is way too broad and story-based and opinion-based to work on this site. Voting to close.

Comment: @TuskyEmonay Alas, worldbuilding don't deal with single characters. This is why it's important to have a "guide to victory" so that it can apply to more than one of them. This being said, I believe you'll find a good inspiration if you look for people who rose quickly in power, you will find some common traits among them... And always a bit of luck, because you need this at this level :).

Comment: VTC. Inventing strategies for characters does seem like writing the story for you, especially a strategy your  whole story depends upon. However your clever girl does it, that cleverness must come from you. The whole story is going to be the reader watching Cinderella somehow whore her way from peasant to Queen; likely killing off hubbies as she goes. My advice: She better be wonderfully attractive, an absolute mindreader at interpreting facial expressions, body language and micro expressions, a fascinating conversationalist and seductress, a revelation in the sack and as ruthless as a spider.

Comment: I was thinking of cosmetic surgery and AI abitlike red rising

Answer (score 1):

That depends on how you construct your society.

Many class or caste conscious societies believe in the inherited superiority of one subdivision of society and a fear that *miscegenation* may dilute it. They would make it much easier to reduce class than to improve it. Historical examples are things like the [one-drop rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-drop_rule) in the United States, [Coloured](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apartheid#Coloured_classification) category in Apartheid-era South Africa, or the [Nuremberg Laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuremberg_Laws) in Nazi-era Germany.

Some class or caste conscious societies believe (or at least pretend to believe) that it isn't an inborn trait, but rather that education and behaviour define class. I find it hard to give *pure* examples, but consider how graduates of a [Grande Ecole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grande_%C3%A9cole) in France or from "[Oxbridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxbridge)" in the UK form a network. Or societies with a deep social gulf between blue-collar workers, white-collar workers, and academics.

So the first requirement would be that your society does not *openly* declare class or caste inheritable. Instead, parents train their children in the behaviour patterns of their caste, and look down on inferior copies and uppity pretenders. It is acceptable to explain to a child which fork to use for the fowl course at a dinner. An adult is expected to get it right, or he or she looks boorish.

The second requirement would be that your society considers *minor* improvements in status as a result of marriage acceptable. If the child of an artisan and the child of an engineer marry, the artisan will be accepted into engineer society, provided he or she tries to fit in and looks embarrassed/cute at any missteps. You could also have institutions such as the [Debutante Ball](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queen_Charlotte%27s_Ball#History) where young women of suitable family were **formally introduced** to the British monarch and hence to high society. It takes somebody who was *formally introduced* before to sponsor a debutante, so this is a kind of self-perpetuating selection process.

With something like this in place at many levels, you could have your character face many different challenges, which all boil down to **being accepted at an incrementally higher society than before.**

- A noble might have an *affair* with the child of an artisan, but the noble would not marry. A noble might marry the child of a merchant, and a merchant might marry the child of an artisan. But perhaps the noble might marry the *widow* of a merchant, no matter that the widow was orignally an artisan?
- Once that noble married the merchant's widow, the wife gets presented at court. She might face many snubs abd [microaggressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microaggression), but open rejection would be a slur against the noble's family, and that would not do.

Answer (score 1):

**Advice on Marrying Up**

It sounds like your culture readily permits marrying up, but has safeguards against the marrages where the couple lacks mutual love.

Let me tell you a story.

A long time ago (before I was born) on a university campus far far away (12 hour time difference from where I live now)...

One of my ancestors caught a classmate checking the financial status of the parents of many of the unattached female students on campus.

My ancestor confronted the fellow and asked what kind of evil gold-digging, nerf-herding scalawag would by trying to see which of the ladies on campus came from wealthy families.

His classmate replied "If I date enough of our female classmates, sooner or later I'll date someone who matches me well and mutual love will happen naturally.”

"And what does that have to do with checking out their family's wealth?” my ancestor asked.

His classmate offered his own question, "If you found Miss Right and got engaged, wouldn't it be nice if her family turned out to be rich?”

"Of course!" said my ancestor.

His classmate smiled and offered up the secret reason for his actions.  "It's just as easy to fall in love with someone rich as someone poor. I can avoid all the problems of marrying into a poor family and have true love plus all the advantages of marrying into a rich family by only dating the ones I know are from rich families.

So, to pass whatever sort of true love test is needed, all your character needs to do is only date those within the target group. Date enough different ones and something will click sooner or later.

**But how to keep moving up?**

Those emotionally shallow enough to engage in such a strategy will find themselves more and more attracted to people in their next...target levels, so would be likely have flings that might lead to divorce and a new marriage to a mutual true (but short-lived) love.

After that, just follow the instructions on the shampoo bottle. "Lather, rinse, repeat.”

Answer (score 0):

Polynesian societies had this, although usually men marrying up rather than women. It wasn't normally allowed but was accomplished a couple of ways.

Eloping and then having a child before returnng to the parents was one way. Usually that first child would be given to the parents as a sort of cultural payment. They may not accept their son/daughter back, but will accept the child. Their son or daughter then lives with their spouse but retains their birth status.

Another way was to do something impressive in war or diplomacy which would give you enough status to marry upwards.

The last practice is probably more common where the man basically lives with the ladies extended family but has the lowest status there and cooks and cleans etc,. Still a good deal for many men as their children will be high status and they themselves gain.

Comment: *"Another way was to do something impressive in war or diplomacy which would give you enough status to marry upwards"* . so gaining the status before marrying, so not gaining any status by marrying, so not an example of *'marrying up'* in the sense used by the OP then  at all .. your last example seems even further off the mark, a protagonist doesn't even gain any status with that one, their children do, and the OP was only interested in the original individual doing the marrying.

Comment: @Pelinore, you're wrong both times. The status gained in the first is very temporary so is either used or lost. In the second they gain by association. They may be the lowliest of a high status house but they still belong to it and anyone messing with them will have to answer to a very strong house.

Comment: You are wrong in both cases because you have not understood what the OP is actually asking, the question has undergone a few edits as the OP attempts to make it acceptable for non-closure but his intent has nonetheless been very clear in comments, though he has deleted some of those .. he is after strategies for one or more individuals to 'climb the greasy pole' using multiple marriages as their primary tool, the status of their children, if they have any, is entirely irrelevant to him.

Comment: @Pelinore suit yourself, I tried explaining. Feel free to downvote.